# How to add client throttling for CloudError: Azure Error: RequestsLimitReached

Tags: python, azure, cloud

Getting an error while creating Azure managed disk snapshot.  Below is the exeception stack and the message returned by Azure cloud

```
Exception call stack:
"Traceback (most recent call last):"
File ""azure/azure.py"", line 188, in createsnapshot"
    disksnapshot = dsksnapshotcreation.result()"
File ""/tmp/myapp/libs/azure/lib/msrest/polling/poller.py"", line 183, in result"
    elf.wait(timeout)"
File ""/tmp/myapp/libs/azure/lib/msrest/polling/poller.py"", line 201, in wait"
    raise self._exception  # type: ignore"
File ""/tmp/myapp/libs/azure/lib/msrest/polling/poller.py"", line 152, in _start"
    self._polling_method.run()"
File ""/tmp/myapp/libs/azure/lib/msrestazure/polling/arm_polling.py"", line 400, in run"
    raise CloudError(self._response)"
"msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: RequestsLimitReached"
```

Message: Too many attempts to copy from a writable resource (a managed disk); please use a snapshot source to create many copies in a short time.

Looks like I need to add some kind of client side throttling. But Azure python SDK does not return throttling information as mentioned in the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling.

How can get information like "retry-after" using python SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you use raw=True in your invoking on create_or_update()?
With that the SDK poller can return http headers returned by service side.